# FindResourceEx and fallback languages

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-mui

I have all translations of a resource in a single executable.  Effectively:

```
STRINGTABLE
  LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, LANG_ENGLISH_US
BEGIN
  IDSTR_HELLO "Hello"
END

STRINGTABLE
  LANGUAGE LANG_SPANISH, LANG_SPANISH_PANAMA
BEGIN
  IDSTR_HELLO "Hola"
END

// ... more languages ...
```

I'm trying to find the (most) appropriate one using [FindResourceEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648043(v=vs.85).aspx) given a LANGID.  A LANGID consists of both the language and a sublanguage.  For example, I might have resources for Spanish as spoken in Panama (`LANGUAGE_SPANISH, SUBLANG_SPANISH_PANAMA`) and Spanish as spoken in Mexico (`LANGUAGE_SPANISH, SUBLANG_SPANISH_MEXICAN`).  When there's an exact match between the desired langid and one of the resources, everything is fine.

If I use FindResourceEx to try to find the resource for a third flavor of Spanish, say (`LANG_SPANISH, SUBLANG_SPANISH_COSTA_RICA`), the find will fail because I don't have a resource specifically for Costa Rica.  In such a case, I'd like to "fall back" to *any* flavor of primary language.

I read something that suggested setting the sublanguage to `SUBLANG_NEUTRAL` should match any resource with the same primary language:

```
HRSRC handle = FindResourceEx(NULL, RT_STRING, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDSTR_HELLO), langid);
if (handle == NULL) {
  fallback_langid = MAKELANGID(PRIMARYLANGID(langid), SUBLANG_NEUTRAL);
  handle = FindResourceEx(NULL, RT_STRING, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDSTR_HELLO), fallback_langid);
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.  Neither does setting the sublanguage to `SUBLANG_DEFAULT`.  (It seems the neutral and default sublanguages are only meaningful when the primary language is also neutral or default.)

What are my options?  Is there a way to enumerate through the resources and do my own comparison of the primary language in the LANGID?  I've been looking at the assortment of EnumResource-like functions, but most of them seem specific to using MUI.  I'm intentionally not using MUI, for various reasons, including the requirement to have all of the translations in a single binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be astonished if you can't use [EnumResourceLanguages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648035(v=vs.85).aspx) without having MUI files. Of course, if all else fails, perhaps you can create a table with a default sub language for every primary language. Or your table could have a default for every primary/sub language pair. You can store this table in your code or in a custom resource.

Comment: Ah, of course EnumResourceLanguages works perfectly.  Thanks!